# Changing variable without influencing view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am displaying a view (ui-router) on the Ionic platform with a message list. New messages should be shown as unread, but then corresponding variables should be changed to read. The problem is that when I set the controller to change the proper variable, the view automatically updates itself immediately with this change and the messages are immediately displayed as read.

How can I deal with this?

In other words: in a variable-dependent view, I want to display the view first and then modify the variable, so that the change of the variable does not affect the view.

The current code (MarkAsRead() is called from within the template):

```
$scope.messages = $rootScope.Messages.Inbox;

$scope.MarkAsRead = function(ID_NR)
{
    angular.forEach($rootScope.Messages.Inbox, function (value, key) {

    if ((value.IsRead == 2) && (value.From == ID_NR))
    {
       value.IsRead = 3;
     }   
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Why do you mark the message as read if you want if to be viewed as unread?

Comment: The variable IsRead should be changed to 3, but that should not be reflected in the view. Only when an user exits the view and then reopens it again that should be reflected. Just like regular read-unread works in many communicators.

Comment: Then change another variable, and when the user exits the view, change your IsRead variable. Not sure what the point of changing the model of a view that doesn't exist anymore, though. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to do this operation just after the view is opened, not at exit, because what if user closes the application without exiting the view? Next time he/she will have the same state (unread), and not read.

Comment: I really fail to understand your logic. Why do you absolutely want to lie to your user. If your application marks the message as read as soon as it's viewed, the show it as read. I fail to see the point of showing it as unread. But anyway, add another variable "initialState" to the message, initialized with the status of the message before it's changed to read, and display that variable in your view, if that's what you want.

Comment: Well, no cheating an user there, it's just the unread messages should be emphasized and placed first in the view, just as simple as that. Anyway I have 1000 elements to manipulate on, so I wanted to limit any mass operations on my variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's odd you're battling the main thing angular is known for: **two-way binding**. That said, if you really want to make changes to the variable without updating the view, you can use `angular.copy` to make a deep copy of the object and manipulate the copy itself. Or display the copy but manipulate the original

Another option, if you're using Angular > 1.3, you can use one-time binding to only update the view first time:

Simply prefix your expression with *::* e.g
`<p>{{::message.IsRead}}</p>`

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Comment: Duplicating the variable seems as the fastest and the least dirty solution. Thank you.

Comment: Well, fastest to implement, but not fastest in execution... This added a considerable amount of lag, unfortunately.

Comment: Then you should try the one time binding. This is one of its use-cases

Comment: I've got not one, but > 30 expressions in the view. Is there any way to apply the solution to all of them or do I have to add {{::message.IsRead}} to each of them?